# Accessing PHP object properties when property name has non allowed chars

Tags: php, oop

I need to access a php object property which I specify as variable.

$phpObj->$property

This $property might contain chars like dash(-), quotes, percent, even whitespace ect. PHP does not allow these chars to be used as variable names, resulting which I am unable to access these properties.

What would be a good solution to handle this? I'm open with encoding the $property to something alphanumeric first and then using it as property variable but this encoding should be unique for a particular string.

Eg, I want to make sure that $phpObj->First-Prop and $phpObj->first-prop  should be identified differently.

Comment: Where are these names coming from? It may be worth using `__get()` and `__set()` to access them from an array.

Comment: Related: [Access a PHP-object with dollar-sign as node name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4378807/access-a-php-object-with-dollar-sign-as-node-name)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$propertyName = 'property-name';

$phpObj->{$propertyName} = ...
$phpObj->{"property-name"} = ...
```

only this may be problem:

```
$phpObj->First-Prop and $phpObj->first-prop
```

variable/function/method/property definitions in php are not case-sensitive...

Comment: Thanks but this case insensitivity might be an issue for me. I'll probably have to rethink my approach

Comment: Had an issue with phpcs `Object property "nodeValue" is not in valid snake_case` when using the trying to get a `nodeValue` of an `attributeNode` part of the [DomDocument Class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).  This workaround helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you wish to achieve here but.
But
you would be best to impliment a whitelist of useable chars, a-zA-Z0-9 im guessing possible _. then you can assign the property knowing that all of the letters are allowed in php.

i dont understand why the properties need unique property names, surely a property of key with a unique value would achieve a similiar thing, could be appended to everything.

php is not case sensetive so $phpObj->First-Prop and $phpObj->First-Prop will take the last property.

i hope that helps, if you have any more on the implimentation and more importantly what you are trying to achieve i'll do my best to help

Comment: if you needed to add case sensitivity you could store them in a property that contains an array. arrays in php are case sensitive. :)

Comment: Thanks. These properties are actually a set of user created tags for that php object. User can create as many tags for an object unless a tag with exact same name (case sensitive) already exists. I also need to store an integer value for each tag which is specific to this object. To  access this integer value I need to access that property. This approach is an attempt implement a Solr response parser for which I had asked a question yesterday http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8132764/storing-and-searching-dynamic-key-value-pairs-in-solr-document

Comment: ok. you could have FphpObj->properties['filed'] =0 and $phpObj->properties['fiELD'] =1; etc. hopefully that may be useful.